# Ideas for stock management using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am creating a database for a publishing company. The company has around 1300 books and around 6-7 offices. Now i have created a table that displays the stock items in all locations. The table should look like following to the **user**:

```
Book Name          Location1            Location2          Location3 ......
History              20000               3000               4354
Computers             4000               688                344
Maths                 3046               300                0
...
```

I already have a Books table which stores all the details of the books, i also have a office table which has the office information. Now if i create a stock management table which shows the information like above i will end up in a huge table with a lot of repetition if i store my data in the following way:

```
Column1- Book_ID   Column2- Location_ID     Column3- Quantity
     1                  1                        20000
     1                  2                        3000
     1                  3                        4354
     2                  1                        4000
     2                  2                        688
   ...
```

So, i think this isn't the best way to store data as it would end up with `1300 (Books) X 7 (Locations) = 9100 rows`. Is there a better way of storing data. Now i can have  7 additional columns in the Books stable but if i create a new location, i will have to add another column to the Books table.

I would appreciate any advice or if you think that the above method is suitable or not.

Comment: Unless you're using Pentium 4 as your server</sarcasm> with correct index InnoDB should be fine with up to 10 million records. Go with this one, it's correct and common solution.

Comment: First suggestion would be to get rid of the location1, location2, location3 columns and have a child table that shows the book id and location id and qty.    In the current structure if you add or remove a location, you have to rework the DB.    If  you go with mysql, stick with standard data types.  don't get in to the weird enums and sets as this is not easily portable to a new platform.

Comment: @Vyktor - Even a Pentium4 should have no problem dealing with this volume of data (assuming the query volume is relatively low)

Comment: @Brian - I'm _pretty_ sure that the top "table" is what the _display_ (ie. application UI) needs to look like, not the actual DB schema.

Comment: he clearly says "The table should look like following:"  then lists location1,2,3 as columns.

Comment: The top table is the representation of table for the UI. That is how it will be shown to the user.

Comment: @Brian - "Now i have create an table that display the stock items in all locations. The table should look like following". The key being _display_, not _store_. A sentance talking about _displaying_ data, followed by talking about what "the table should look like", indicates UI. Especially when he describes the database structure in the next paragraph.

Comment: He doesn't say it is UI.  and assuming that is a mistake unless and until the op clarifies.

Comment: @Brian Please check the updated question, hope that clarifies the UI and the structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's the best way to do it.

What you have is a Many-to-Many relationship between Books and Locations. This is, in almost *all* cases, stored in the database as an "associative" table between the two main entities. In your case, you also have additional information about that association, namely, it's "stock" or "quantity" (or, if you think about it like a Graph, the *magnitude* of the connection, or edge-weight).

So, it might *seem* like you have a lot of "duplication", but you don't really. If you were to try to do it any other way, it would be *much* less flexible. For example, with the design you have now, it doesn't require *any* database schema change to add another thousand different books or another 20 locations.

If you were to try to put the book quantities inside the Locations table, or the Locations inside the Books table, it would require you to change the layout of the database, and then re-test any code that might be use it.

Comment: But this will lead to 1300 extra rows each time i add another office?

Comment: generally yes but is ok, because office has 1300 books then you should have 1300 rows to store that informations

Comment: Not necessarily; if the quantity is zero for a given book at a given location, the row could simply be omitted. But what's 1300 rows? That's really nothing for any decent database system.

Comment: @Namit - As the others have said, an extra couple of thousand rows is not going to have much of a performance impact on the database, especially if you have indexes on the fields that are used for querying data. Adding 10,000 rows might have an impact when you insert them, but even then, as long as there are indexes, you should have no problem at all. Also, having the absence of a row in the association table mean "no inventory" or "0", you can limit the number of rows needed to only track inventory you _have_ rather than inventory you _don't have_.

Answer (score 2):

Thats the most common (and effective) solution. Most frameworks like Django, Modx and several others implement Many2Many relations via an intermediate table only, using foreign key relations.

Make sure you index your table properly.

```
ALTER TABLE stock_management add index (Book_ID), add index (Location_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

That really the best way to do it; you have 9100 independent data to store, so you really do need 9100 rows (less, really; the rows where the quantity is 0 can be omitted.) Other way of arranging the data would require the structure of the table to change when a location was added.